# How do I store data from a form in a text file in the server?

Tags: html, forms, http, webserver

I am using a Raspberry Pi running raspbian, a debian distro and am using lighttpd as a http server, How do I store the data that is input on the form in a text file in the Raspberry Pi(the server)? And would I have to run lighttpd as sudo? If so how? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Installing CGI support you could have Python: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1346/how-to-get-python-to-work-with-lighttpd

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something that allow you write custom handling logic for that data, like Python or another lightweight framework.

Installing CGI support you could have Python: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1346/how-to-get-python-to-work-with-lighttpd

Cheers.